# In 3D ${\cal N}=2$ SUSY, the linear multiplet contains a global current. How is this related to the gauge field?

Tags: conservation-laws, gauge-theory, supersymmetry, research-level, noethers-theorem

I am reading the paper on 3d $\mathcal{N}=2$ supersymmetry by O. Aharony et al. (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9703110) and I am a bit confused about linear multiplets in section 2.3. A linear multiplet is defined as $\Sigma = \epsilon^{\alpha\beta} \bar{D}_{\alpha}D_{\beta} V$ where $V$ is the vector multiplet corresponding to a $U(1)$ gauge symmetry. Then they say the linear multiplet can be used to describe global currents generating a $U(1)_{J}$ global symmetry. What kind of current is this and what does it has to do with the $U(1)$ gauge symmetry of the vector multiplet $V$ $\Sigma$ is built out of? My confusion is that the gauge symmetry of $V$ is a local $U(1)$ symmetry, not a global one. Or do they just mean the current corresponding to global gauge transformations as a subset of the local transformations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A linear multiplet is defined as $\Sigma=\epsilon^{\dot{\alpha}\beta}\bar{D}_{\dot{\alpha}}D_{\beta}V$ where $V$ is the vector multiplet corresponding to a U(1) gauge symmetry.

You have no "dotted indices" for the representations of the Lorentz group in $d=3$ (since the (real) Lorentz algebra is $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ or $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ for the Minkowskian/Euclidean spacetime respectively).
Moreover the definition is valid for any gauge symmetry vector potential, not only $\mathsf{U}(1)$.

> What kind of current is this and what does it has to do with the U(1) gauge symmetry of the vector multiplet V Σ is built out of?

When you reduce the $d=4,\mathcal{N}=1$ theory to $d=3,\mathcal{N}=2$ (the crucial point is that you have $4$ generators of SUSY in both theories) the vector superpotential decomposes as 
\begin{equation}
V=-i\theta\bar{\theta}\sigma -\theta\gamma^i\bar{\theta} A_i+i\theta^2\bar{\theta}\bar{\lambda}-\bar{\theta}^2\theta\lambda +\frac{1}{2}\theta^2\bar{\theta}^2 D,\end{equation}
where $\sigma$ is now a (Lorentz) scalar field which corresponds to the component of the $d=4$ vector field in the reduced direction. 
The scalar $\sigma$ can take a VEV which breaks the gauge group to its maximal torus $\mathsf{U}(1)^{\operatorname{rank}\mathfrak{g}}$ (topologically this is $(\mathbb{S}^1)^r$, i.e. an $r$-torus), thus to each Abelian factor you can associate a stress-energy field $F^i$. For simplicity, let's take the case of only one Abelian factor, and call $F_{ij}$ the corresponding field strength, which is a Lie algebra valued $2$-form, then in $d=3$ the Hodge star will map it to a Lie algebra valued $1$-form, which is closed (Maxwell's eqns.), hence locally exact, we can introduce a scalar field $\gamma$ and write (locally)
\begin{equation}
\phi:= \sigma+i\gamma,\quad \star_3F=d\gamma,
\end{equation}
$\gamma$ is known as the dualised scalar photon. Now the crucial point is that its charge is quantised, i.e.
\begin{equation}
q=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int F\in\mathbb{Z},
\end{equation}
therefore the $\gamma$ field is compact, which is to say, $\phi$ and $\phi+2\pi i$ are to be identified, or equivalently the action is invariant w.r.t. a shift of $\gamma$ by $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$: we call this symmetry $\mathsf{U}(1)_{\scriptscriptstyle\rm J}$ or topological symmetry. As you can see from $d\star_3F=0$, $J\sim\star_3F$ is the generator of the $\mathsf{U}(1)_{\scriptscriptstyle\rm J}$ global symmetry, with conserved charge $\sim q$ (the precise proportionality factors depend on your definitions). Defining 
\begin{equation}
\Sigma=-\frac{i}{2}\epsilon^{{\alpha}\beta}\bar{D}_{{\alpha}}D_{\beta}V,
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
2\pi J=\sigma+\dots+\frac{1}{2}\theta\gamma^i\bar{\theta}(\star_3F)_i.
\end{equation}

Try looking at appendices A and B of this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.6684 for a more careful explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and the link! I do have some questions though, why is the charge defined as the integral over the field strength and not the dual field strength? The construction seems to depend on the fact that you can replace the field strength in the lagrangian with the dual field strength, is that true and when is this possible? The linear multiplet is still built up from a vector multiplet which is the susy extension of the gauge field which arises from local $U(1)$ symmetry, how do go from a local to a global symmetry? Thanks!

Comment: And does this mean that any other term then pure Yang-Mills will break the coulomb branch to $\mathcal{R}$? For instance a Chern-Simons term or a chiral field coupled to a gauge symmetry via $\bar{\phi} e^V \phi$?